# Every row in a table has different meta data columns

Tags: database, postgresql, database-design

I am working on designing an inventory system that I'd like to be structured for high scalability of actions to update items in inventory.

Right now I have an actions table where every row is a particular action upon a single item. The table has an action_type_id column that links to another table containing all the possible actions that can take place.

The Problem: Every action (Purchase, Sale, Scrap, Return, etc) can have different meta data columns that need to be filled out for that action. Over time, there could be potentially hundreds of meta data columns that would be selectively required depending on the action being inserted.

The Question: What's the best strategy to use in this situation? I'd like to keep all the actions together, but it doesn't make sense to include all the metadata columns.

Things I've considered:

- Splitting up every action into its own table.
- For every action creating an ACTION_TYPE_details table that only has columns for that actions meta data. I would probably enforce that each metadata table has a 1 to 1 relationship to the action in the actions table. I'm leaning towards this option the most right now.
- Creating a single separate Action_Details table that would hold the columns for all the possible types of metadata. Again though, this would make consistency hard to enforce.
- Adding lots of optional detail columns to the actions table.

Comment: Use a `jsonb` column that stores those meta data values

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Interesting option. If I went this route, how could I handle metadata that would otherwise be a foreign key column?  For example, purchase and sale actions could have a link to a receipt through a many actions to 1 receipt relationship.  I assume you can't put foreign key relationships in the jsonb data type.

Comment: This is a well-known dilemma in the world of relational databases - and the answer is - it depends on your specific needs. One option is, as a horse with no name wrote, to store the meta data as json (or xml, or whatever) - making it a "property bag" - that can simplify the database structure but not very useful if you need to use that meta data as foreign keys. Another option is to use EAV which is usually considered an anti-pattern, and suffers from the same drawbacks as the property bag solution, and the other options you've already covered on the question's text. Basically, it's up to you.